# How to do 'get_managed_users' in the new Box Windows SDK?

Tags: c#

I have inherited an older C# console application that makes the call to https://www.box.com/api/1.0/rest?action=get_managed_users and receives back XML data containing data for all of the users. I'm guessing this is related to the "Get All Users in an Enterprise" referenced in the API documentation (https://developers.box.com/docs/#users-get-all-the-users-in-an-enterprise), but not totally sure.

My question...using the newer "box-windows-sdk-v2-master" SDK, is there a way to perform this same action and return a list of users in the system? I'm not seeing anything in the code for it.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Kevin